# how can I print dictionary whose key is tuple and value is tuple in table format?

Tags: python, typeerror

```
for k, v in sorted(total_prob.items(), key = lambda x: x[1], reverse=True):
    MLE_Prob, Bi_Prob = v
    # here, k = tuple type of bigrams. v = tuple type of (mle prob, bi prob)
    print tabulate([k,v[0], v[1]], headers = ["Bigram", "MLE_Prob", "Bi_Prob"], tablefmt="grid")
```

my data consists like, {(a,b) : (c,d)}. and the result I wanna print is

```
header1     header2    header3
(a, b)         c          d
```

but I got type error, 'float'object is not iterable. 
mle prob and bi prob are both float and its value is usually 0.0022323xxx something like that. 
How can dissolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you need to create array with your results, and then display it using tabulate. You cannot display row by row, but whole grid at once.

```
from tabulate import tabulate

total_prob = {("a", "b"): (1, 2), ("c", "d"): (3, 4)}
results = []
for k, v in sorted(total_prob.items(), key = lambda x: x[1], reverse=True):
    MLE_Prob, Bi_Prob = v
    results.append([k,MLE_Prob, Bi_Prob])

print tabulate(results, headers = ["Bigram", "MLE_Prob", "Bi_Prob"], tablefmt="grid")
```

Output:

```
+------------+------------+-----------+
| Bigram     |   MLE_Prob |   Bi_Prob |
+============+============+===========+
| ('c', 'd') |          3 |         4 |
+------------+------------+-----------+
| ('a', 'b') |          1 |         2 |
+------------+------------+-----------+
```

---

Tabulate takes an array of arrays (array of rows) as first argument. So at least you needed to use tabulate like this: `tabulate([[k,v[0], v[1]]],...` but then output will be like this:

```
+------------+------------+-----------+
| Bigram     |   MLE_Prob |   Bi_Prob |
+============+============+===========+
| ('c', 'd') |          3 |         4 |
+------------+------------+-----------+
+------------+------------+-----------+
| Bigram     |   MLE_Prob |   Bi_Prob |
+============+============+===========+
| ('a', 'b') |          1 |         2 |
+------------+------------+-----------+
```